# How can i flatten a dict in Pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

Pyparsing allows named lexer components (or using `setResultsName` for the same purpose) that after parsing can be used as attributes or dict entries.

This allows a nice flat view of most parsed components... except, when you need to replace the matched tokens in a specific way.

In my case i want to transform and duplicate them. So i created a function like this:

```
def process_comments(_1,_2,token):
    urls = []
    comments = []
    #...transform here...
    return {"list":comments, "urls":urls}

comments = ZeroOrMore(Suppress(Keyword("comment")) + quotes.copy()).setParseAction(process_comments)
comments.setResultsName("comments")
```

This works, but causes a unneeded map depth (and gets worse with nested substitutions). I'd much prefer to be able to create two entries at the top level the result, 'comments' and 'urls' and leave the original token to the void.

Can this be done? Remember, the transform is not part of the original input, just the original token, so this needs to be post-parsing modification, or something weird must be done on the grammar.

I'd be cool if there was a way to add a`Empty` token that i could customize with setParseAction to get the last matched token (that isn't empty) but there isn't right?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that to flatten this i just add to add my 'setParserAction' up to the parent of the comments grammar. It has all the information after its own parse of the child and can replace itself, thus 'flatten' or duplicate or transform the child.